# How to convert QGIS Field Calculation to ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have a field calculator expression I use in QGIS to generate unique IDs that are sequential, but start with a text string.  I now need to perform the same thing in ArcGIS, but I am unsure of how to start.  Here is my QGIS expression:

```
 'cos' || ( tostring(  $rownum  + 1000000))
```

I was thinking that in ArcGIS it would be something like this:

```
 "cos"+InStr( [FID] + 1000000 )
```

But it returned an error.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few different ways to do this in ArcGIS Field Calculator.

If you are fine with basing the `ID` on the `FID`, you can use:

```
"cos" + str(!FID! + 1000000) - make sure you set Field Calculator to Python
```

or

```
"cos + CStr([FID] + 1000000) - make sure you set Field Calculator to VB
```

If you want your unique IDs to be sequential and not based on the `FID` the easiest way is to use a Python codeblock in your Field Calculation:

Codeblock:

```
rec = 1000000
def autoIncrement():
  global rec
  id = "cos" + rec
  rec += 1
  return id
```

Expression:

```
autoIncrement()
```

The above function will start at the first record in your table with `cos1000000` and add `1` to each new record like `cos1000001, cos1000002, etc...`